# jQuery li click event fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a click event for the `li` element using jQuery. This event is fired twice for some reason, can anyone spot where my mistake is?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    @foreach (var group in Model)
    {
        <li class="group">@group.GroupDesc</li>
    }
</ul>
```

**Java script:**

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function (e) {
    var li = this;
    alert(li.innerHTML);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.group
{
    margin:4px;
    padding-top:60px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    color:White;
    background-color:#00b5fa;
    font-weight:bold;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    border:3px solid #059ae4;
}
```

Comment: is it inside another ul with same class?

Comment: no it's not @Pranav C Balan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your event gets bind twice, so try by unbinding previously bound eventHandler before binding new one.

```
$('ul.menu li').unbind("click");

$('ul.menu li').click(function (e) {
    var li = this;
    alert(li.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: You're right the event was binding twice. I simply moved the code to a different location and now it's only firing once and I don't have to call unbind.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function (e) {
    var li = this;
    alert(li.innerHTML);
    return false ;  // e.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$("ul.menu li").off().on("click", function(e) {
        var li = this;
        alert(li.innerHTML);       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after alert(li.innerHTML);

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Just to add more information about the `stopPropagation` : It will stop the click event from bubbling to parent elements (Very usefull when you have multiple ul containing other ul. For the `preventDefault`, it prevent the control to use it's default behavior. E.g. An anchor with an empty `href=""` would refresh the page without a `$(this).preventDefault()` in the `click()` method.